# Where to call method to automatically increment loan

Tags: c#, methods

I have been able to create a method to increment a person's loan balance every 30 days but I do not know where in the C# windows forms application to call this method so that the loan balance is constantly recalculated so that it can be incremented. Should i call it under main form load? or all forms related to loan?

if you are curious the method goes like this:

```
 public static void AutoIncrementAndFlag()
    {
        string select = "select cusnumber,loandate from loan where loanstatus = 'Active'";
        SqlDataReader readnumberanddate = GetData(select).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        SortedList<string, string> numberanddate = new SortedList<string, string>();
        while (readnumberanddate.Read())
        {
            numberanddate.Add(readnumberanddate["cusNumber"].ToString(), readnumberanddate["loandate"].ToString());
        }
        readnumberanddate.Close();
        foreach(var key in numberanddate.Keys)
        {
            DateTime datetaken = DateTime.Parse(numberanddate[key]);
            DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan daysbetween = currentdate - datetaken;
            string diff2 = daysbetween.ToString("%d");//convert the time you found into a single digit by turning it into a string
            int intdiff = int.Parse(diff2);//convert number of days from string format to be able to do math on it
            int res = intdiff / 30;//now divide the days by 30 and use the result in a loop as I will below
            int resflag = res % 60;
            if (res > 0)
            {
                
                string getbal = $"select loanbalance from Loan where cusNumber='{key}' AND loanstatus='Active'";
                SqlDataReader readbalance = GetData(getbal).ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                List<string> balance = new List<string>();
                while (readbalance.Read())
                {
                    balance.Add(readbalance["loanbalance"].ToString());
                }
                readbalance.Close();
                int count = 0;
                double loanbalance = double.Parse(balance[0]);
                while (count < res)
                {
                    loanbalance = loanbalance + 0.10 * loanbalance;

                }
                //now build my update string
                string update = $"UPDATE Loan set loanbalance =@1 where cusnumber=@2 AND loanstatus=@3";
              
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(update, dbase.Connected());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", loanbalance);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", key);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3",statusactive);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                //now loan has been automatically incremented I just need to know where to locate methods now
            }
            if (resflag >= 2)
            {
                //we flag customer red here
                string update = "UPDATE customer set flag =@1 where cusnumber =@2 ";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(update,dbase.Connected());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", "Red");
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", key);
            }


            
        }
    }
```

The method is created in a class called Registration and below is how the table looks
[the loan table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egktu.png)

Comment: Side note: you're allowed to use text names in your SQL parameters; `"UPDATE Loan set loanbalance = @loanbal where cusnumber=@cusno AND loanstatus=@stat"`. Your code elsewhere has examples of reasonable variable naming e.g. `TimeSpan daysbetween = currentdate - datetaken;` - there's no penalty and only upsides to applying a sensible naming strategy everywhere

Comment: *`//convert the time you found into a single digit by turning it into a string`* - also worth pointing out that this should not be done; do not use string as some intermediary trip for things that can and should remain as numbers. TimeSpan has a `.Days` property that is the number of whole days. It also has a decimal `.TotalDays` such as 1.5, which would be a `.Days = 1 and .Hours = 12`. You do not need to turn a timespan to a string and back to an int to get the number of days as an int; `.Days` is an int, and `.TotalDays` can be made so with a cast  (truncates 1.5 down to 1)

Comment: If you're going to make a method that e.g. runs and calculates loan balances, take a look at mking it idempotent - this means that no matter how many times you run it, it shouldn't result in a different outcome for the same inputs. For example, don't write it such taht a new record is added every time it runs; write it so that an existing record is updated/ignored, and a new record is only added if one isn't there already. This then helps mean that users cannot cause problems by triggering it twice either by accident or through ignorance.

Comment: @CaiusJard thank you I understood most of your points and I am happy I learned more about time span. But another problem has come. The method just refuses to run , no error message nothing happens it just loads and loads and loads but if I comment out the method call the program starts to run. What could be the problem?

Comment: Normally an indication that a query is taking a very long time. On which line does it "load and load and load"?